# Firebase User Opt Out of Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

With Firebase Analytics, is it possible to configure it so that a user can set a preference and opt-out of being tracked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can default Firebase Analytics to disabled by adding the following meta-data to the application element in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled" android:value="false" />
```

To enable Firebase Analytics per individual instance you can then call:

```
FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
```

Once you make the call the value is persisted on the device and will remain in effect until you make another call to `setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled`. Once set the value has effect on all events logged after the call from any process or thread on the device. If your app is using multiple processes you only need to make the call once. More details in [official guide](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Had some trouble with the support pages the other night, so I missed this. I made this a user preference so they could opt out. Seems to work well. Firebase console isn't showing much at this point, but I can see the output when I enable the verbose logging in ADB.

Comment: is there a way to see like on iOS that it is infact set to the value we set it to ? because even when I call setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true); I still see this in the console firebase_analytics_collection_enabled=0

Answer (score 1):

The support page shows how you can [temporarily disable](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics#temporarily_disable_collection) Analytics collection, such as to get end-user consent before collecting data.

Comment: Thank you, I will check them again. I was having trouble with the support pages last night. They kept coming up 404.

Comment: Ok. Please accept the answer if it works for you, so others don't spend time asking/answering the same question.

Comment: I will when I look later tonight. Thanks